# How to download a generated excel file from your asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, excel, export-to-excel, download

I am building an asp.net website and I am constructing a Excel document based on some gridview data. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to construct it. I have tried to use a `saveFileDialog` box using `System.Windows.Forms`. Through my research online, I have learned that you can’t actually do this in an asp.net application? Everything works great in debugging mode, but when uploading it to the site, the page doesn't work at all. So my man question is, is it possible to to use a `saveFileDialog` box for an asp.net application? Does anyone know a good workaround for this? I will post my code that works great in debugging mode, but doesn't work when I upload it to my site. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
using System.Threading;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

public void someEvent()
{
    var t = new Thread(SaveFolder);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

public void SaveFolder()
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Sources (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls*;*.xlsx"; 
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    exportReport();
}

public void exportReport()
{
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlApp);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
}

public void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably showing the dialog... on your server, where there's nobody there to see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show a dialog box on the server. There's nobody there to see it. Get rid of the whole saveFileDialog object and just call SaveAs with a generated filename in the server's file system that is guaranteed to be unique. Then transmit that file to your user.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want to with the save dialog. You should just save the file to a temporary location on your server. Once you have the file saved somewhere, you can force the file at the user for download. I usually follow this code (seems to work in all browsers the most consistently). You have to supply the `filename` and `yourFileByteArray` variables.

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.CacheControl = "public";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "Excel File Download");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

Response.BinaryWrite(yourFileByteArray);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

There are several ways to get your file as a byte array, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: so the Response.BinaryWrite() is where you force your user to download the file you saved to your temporary location? correct? why cant you just use Response.WriteFile() or something, because technically the file exists now correct?

Comment: You don't have any control over the user's file system. The user has to choose to save a file. The best you can do is force the file to the browser, as the above code does via the Response. The browser and the user have to agree to put the file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help Cory, your explanations really gave me a better understanding of what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Interop. Suggest using a mix of HtmlTextWriter, StringWriter, and your GridView.

```
public void GridViewToExcel()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFile.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

    var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);

    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    Response.Write(writer.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: If you cant use interop, how do you format your excel file just the way you want it?

Comment: Either using the OpenXML version of Excel files (2007+), or tools like Aspose. Interop Excel is not thread safe, has horrible performance, and requires Excel to be installed on the server. It works but isn't ideal.